# How do you get "Box" values out of "Array" in Python for use with `click()`?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, image-processing, click, pyautogui

NOTE: Using `PyAutoGui` library

I am trying to make python click on each icon on screen in order, I have gotten it to successfully print each item on screen with it's `box` values of *left* and *top* in place of X and Y coordinates. But I can't figure out how to get left/top converted into X/Y values for use with the `pyautogui.click()`

Code:

```
import pyautogui

coordinates = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('eachIcon.png')
for element in coordinates:
    print(element)
```

Prints:

```
Box(left=124, top=699, width=14, height=14)
```

**What command would I use to extract Left and Top as X and Y number coordinates?**

I am entirely new to python and practically new to coding (took a beginners class of C++ in college). I've spent a good hour googling and trying every term I can think of, I'm stumped: hence the post.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will need to unpack a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_tuples.htm):

Box has 4 objects `Box(left=124, top=699, width=14, height=14)` to unpack Box we can just add 4 dummy variables (since we only need x,y) to your for code

`for x, y, _, _ in coordinates:` or `for x, y, w, h in coordinates` if you also want the weight and height

I inserted the dummy variables because otherwise we will get a ValueError.
The error occurs when the number of variables doesn't match the number of values so if we had `for x, y in coordinates:` we would get a ValueError.

You could also access a tuple by doing
`x = [0]`
`y = [1]`
But i suggest you to use the for code since you also want to click them in order

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in detail, as a novice this level of explanation is very helpful!

I will try it as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

coordinates.left coordinates.right etc should do the trick